Can any full rank matrix have its rows and columns permuted such that none of the minors in the cofactor expansion are zero?
I am wondering if for an arbitrary full rank square matrix $X$ with non-zero entries we can acquire a matrix $Y$ purely through permutations of the rows and columns of $X$ such that all of the minors $m_{1, j}$ in the Laplace (cofactor) expansion
$$
  0 \neq \det(Y) = \sum_{j = 1}^n (-1)^{j + 1} y_{1, j} m_{1, j}
$$
are non-zero.

You can't do this for the identity matrix, can you? Just find any zero entry in the permuted matrix, its cofactor be $n-1\times n-1$ but have only $n-2$ nonzero entries.

@GerryMyerson You're right, I will update the question with the condition that I forgot to include which is that the entries are non-zero. Not sure if it still admits a counterexample, but at least not one quite so obvious.

Note that permuting rows and columns preserves the cofactors, so if your original matrix has a zero minor, so do all of its permutations.

Indeed, although only $n$ of the possible minors need to be considered in the Laplace expansion.

Oh, you're taking the expansion to be along the first row. Cofactor and minor are more general concepts, they can be with respect to any location in the matrix. Still, I think $$A=\pmatrix{6&3&2\cr2&1&1\cr3&1&1\cr}$$ will be an example. No matter how you permute, one of the entries on the diagonal of $A$ will wind up in the first row, and all three diagonal entries have minor equal to zero.

Let
$$
A=\pmatrix{6&3&2\cr2&1&1\cr3&1&1\cr}
$$
Then $A$ is a full-rank square matrix with nonzero entries. All of the minors $m_{j,j}$ of elements on the diagonal are zero. No matter where a matrix entry winds up after row and/or column permutations, its minor will not change, except possibly for its sign – in particular, if its minor in $A$ is zero, it will always be zero. And no matter what row and/or column permutations one performs, one of the entries that starts out on the diagonal will end up in the first row. So, the minors $m_{1,j}$ will not all be nonzero.
